# Debian Guest NAT in KVM cannot access apt-get

Tags: debian, kvm, proxy

Hello colleagues I have Debian 8 Jessie latest update as host on my laptop, from host I am connecting through VPN tunnel to the proxy and then to internet.
Connection to the internet from host is working apt-get is installing everything.
I have created Debian 8 Jessie guests in KVM with NATed interface. I can reach Proxy from guests but I cannot go through proxy to the internet.

I dont have any proxy exported in guests. 
What should I change in guests to be able to pass through proy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer solved, proxy needs to be also inside of VMs. :)